# Iptables duplicate/Mirror incoming UDP traffic from HOST1 to an external HOST2

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing, udp, forwarding

I need an advice about the following scenario:

- IoT devices are sending UDP packets to a 18.04 Ubuntu server environment (HOST1) on port 1234.
- HOST1 processes the UDP packets as per the internal configuration
- **I need to**: Duplicate/mirror those incoming UDP packets from HOST1 to another external server (HOST2) after they are processed by HOST1

Is this possible to achieve using `iptables`?

1. This command cannot be used because it's not duplicating the UDP packets as per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377407/iptables-process-a-packet-locally-and-send-a-copy-to-another-host) thread:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination IP_HOST_B:3333`

2. The `TEE` target cannot be used either because it's duplicating the packets **locally** (as per the same thread). I need to mirror the UDP packets to an external host.

Note: I don't need to duplicate any outgoing traffic, just the original UDP packets which are received by HOST1.

**UPDATE:** I don't care if the UDP packets are duplicated/mirrored before or after being processed by HOST1, as long as they are processed, not just forwaded.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal and the details of udp mirroring on below link are same.
https://zapier.com/engineering/iptables-replication/